# Need Malware removal instructions

Tags: adware

How do I remove `mysearchresults.com` and `funmoods.com` adware from my HP laptop ?

I am using Internet Explorer. The uninstall function does not work, as I cannot locate these toolbars on the list. Also tried the tools function on IE but it only showed disable function.

Comment: Probably a spam seed.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-mysearchresults-search/) is an article to read about mysearchresults.com. Please note this is considered aggressive-adware/browser-hijacking, and not malware.

[Here](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/funmoods-virus/) is one for funmoods.com

Summed up:

Note: If you have any computer experience, you *may* want to go through some of the lists that the tools pop up with, just to make sure there is nothing you explicitly recognize that you don't want deleted. It most likely won't be an issue, though

STEP 1 : Uninstall GadgetBoxa and Funmoods programs from your computer

1. Navigate to Programs and Features
2. When the Programs and Features or the Uninstall a Program screen is displayed, scroll through the list of currently installed programs and uninstall Default Tab, Default Tab for Chrome, Browser Protect and any other recently installed unknown program from your computer. To view the most recently installed programs, you can click on the “Installed On” column to sort your program by the installation date. Scroll though the list, and uninstall any unwanted or unknown programs.

STEP 2: Remove MySearchResults virus from Internet Explorer (If you have other browsers, please visit the link for instructions for them too, as it is highly probable that it will affect them too)

1. Open Internet Explorer, click on the “gear icon” in the upper right part of your browser, then click again on Internet Options.
2. In the “Internet Options” dialog box, click on the “Advanced” tab, then click on the “Reset” button.
3. In the “Reset Internet Explorer settings” section, select the “Delete personal settings” check box, then click on “Reset” button.
4. When Internet Explorer has completed its task, click on the “Close” button in the confirmation dialogue box. You will now  need to close your browser, and then you can open Internet Explorer again.

STEP 3: Remove MySearchResults browser hijacker with AdwCleaner

1. Download AdwCleaner utility (I would post the link, but I don't have enough reputation on this site for more than two links. It is included in the above article)
2. Before starting AdwCleaner, close all open programs and internet browsers, then double-click on the AdwCleaner icon. If Windows prompts you as to whether or not you wish to run AdwCleaner, please allow it to run.
3. When the AdwCleaner program will open, click on the “Scan” button. AdwCleaner will now start to search for the “MySearchResults” malicious files that may be installed on your computer.
4. To remove the “MySearchResults” malicious files that were detected in the previous step, please click on the “Clean” button.
5. AdwCleaner will now prompt you to save any open files or documents, as the program will need to reboot the computer. Please do so and then click on the OK button.

STEP 4: Remove MySearchResults virus from your computer with Malwarebytes Anti-Malware Free

1. You can download download Malwarebytes Anti-Malware from either article link.
2. Once downloaded, close all programs, then double-click on the icon on your desktop named “mbam-setup-consumer-2.00.xx” to start the installation of Malwarebytes Anti-Malware. You may be presented with a User Account Control dialog asking you if you want to run this file. If this happens, you should click “Yes” to continue with the installation.
3. When the installation begins, you will see the Malwarebytes Anti-Malware Setup Wizard which will guide you through the installation process. To install Malwarebytes Anti-Malware on your machine, keep following the prompts by clicking the “Next” button.
4. Once installed, Malwarebytes Anti-Malware will automatically start and you will see a message stating that you should update the program, and that a scan has never been run on your system. To start a system scan you can click on the “Fix Now” button. Alternatively, you can click on the “Scan” tab and select “Threat Scan“, then click on the “Scan Now” button.
5. Malwarebytes Anti-Malware will now check for updates, and if there are any, you will need to click on the “Update Now” button.
6. Malwarebytes Anti-Malware will now start scanning your computer for the MySearchResults virus.
7. When the scan has completed, you will now be presented with a screen showing you the malware infections that Malwarebytes’ Anti-Malware has detected. To remove the malicious programs that Malwarebytes Anti-malware has found, click on the “Quarantine All” button, and then click on the “Apply Now” button.
8. Malwarebytes Anti-Malware will now quarantine all the malicious files and registry keys that it has found. When removing the files, Malwarebytes Anti-Malware may require a reboot in order to remove some of them. If it displays a message stating that it needs to reboot your computer, please allow it to do so.

STEP 5: Double check for the MySearchResults infection with HitmanPro

1. You can download HitmanPro from either article link.
2. Double-click on the file named “HitmanPro.exe” (for 32-bit versions of Windows) or “HitmanPro_x64.exe” (for 64-bit versions of Windows). Click on the “Next” button, to install HitmanPro on your computer.
3. HitmanPro will now begin to scan your computer for MySearchResults malicious files.
4. When it has finished it will display a list of all the malware that the program found as shown in the image below. Click on the “Next” button, to remove MySearchResults malware.
5. Click on the “Activate free license” button to begin the free 30 days trial, and remove all the malicious files from your computer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You need to put the "meat" of the subject to the links you have supplied. Links break and become useless to future visitors.

Comment: You're right. Working on that now

Comment: @CarlB How's this? :D